# WPF RichTextBox cleared the firstline text when pressing the 'Enter' Key

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, richtextbox

I have a WPF Project (with MVVM Light) that contains a `RichTextBox` control with `Toolbar` like below image[image]

I try to store the formatted text ( user can change rich text box content style to 'Bold','Italics','underline' or increase or decrease the font size ) to sql lite database.

I am using TextRange class to capture the `RichTextBox` content.

```
 /* Get Richtext box text. */
 TextRange range;
 range = new TextRange(((FlowDocument)document).ContentStart,
                      ((FlowDocument)document).ContentEnd);
 /* Get Richtext box text. */
```

But it's not captured correct text if the text is bold or italics. I googled many hours, but i can't find a right method to my requirement. Please advice if anyone have idea.

Comment: Can you expand on "not captured correct text" - do you mean the range.Text property is wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I mean when i input some text with bold or italics style, it's not captured the text with given style. 'TextRange' is not captured the text style, it's only captured the text only.

Comment: Ah I understand. I am not sure exactly where the formatting for a range is, but I think you may need to save and load the raw RTF data to achieve what you want as this will contain the formatting data. Bare with and I will write an answer if you're happy with this approach?

Comment: Yes, please proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where the formatting data is stored in relation to the rich text box properties, but the TextRange.Text property is just a raw string of text.

My approach would be the extract the raw RTF data and save/load this accordingly. This also has the advantages of being able to be opened in any other rich text editor such as Microsoft Word.

To get an RTF string representation you can use this code:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var doc = RichTextBox.Document;
var range = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);
range.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
string rtfString = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());

//You can then save this string to the database or whatever you want...
```

and to load an RTF string back into the RichTextBox you can use this code.

```
string rtfText = LoadTextFromDatabase() //However you read the saved string..
var ms = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(rtfText));
RichTextBox.Selection.Load(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

Hope this helps and is a suitable solution for you.